# Login Form not logging in - Sessions returning Null Limit 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

Rails learner here, attempting something new by building an application that has two halves, one half corporates the other half students.

Have built out out corporates to have its own controller and model and students to have its own controller and model where both user types login through the same form. (i know i could have created it in a more role based manner using a column to denote user type however the segregation made more sense to me from a learning perspective)

My problem, when signing up as a new user, it logs in fine, however as a returning user(student or corporate) it never logs in, even when entering the new credentials the login page keeps rendering.

From what i understand it is because when searching the DB to authenticate the user instead of searching via email, the its searching where email is NULL LIMIT 1...

SELECT  "corporates".* FROM "corporates" WHERE "corporates"."email" IS NULL LIMIT 1

Any help would be so appreciated, learning rails is certainly a journey!

Hopefully i've posted enough components, let me know if theres anything ive missed.

---

Sessions Controller

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end


  def create
      if
        @corporate = Corporate.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
        session[:corporate_id] = @corporate.id
        flash[:notice] = "Welcome back, #{corporate.firstname}!"
        redirect_to (session[:intended_url] || @corporate)
        session[:intended_url] = nil

      elsif 
        @student = Student.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])

        if params[:remember_me]
              cookies.permanent[:auth_token] = student.auth_token
            else
              cookies[:auth_token] = student.auth_token
        end
        flash[:notice] = "Welcome back, #{student.firstname}!"
        redirect_to (session[:intended_url] || student)
        session[:intended_url] = nil
      else
        flash.now[:warning] = "Kindly login with your email and password!"
        redirect_to '/login'
        #render :new
      end 
    end




 def destroy
    if current_corporate
      session.delete(:student_id) || cookies.delete(:auth_token)
    else current_corporate
      session[:corporate_id] = nil
    end
    redirect_to root_url, notice: "You have signed out!"
  end


  def logged_in?
    !current_corporate.nil?
  end


end
```

Corporates Controller

```
class CorporatesController < ApplicationController


  def index
      @Corporates = corporate.paginate(page: params[:page], :per_page => 5).includes(:profile)
  end

  def show
  if params[:id] 
      @corporate = Corporate.find(params[:id])
      # .includes(:profile)
    else 
      @corporate = current_corporate
    end
    @searches = Search.where(corporate_id: @corporate).includes(:state, city: [:profile])

  end


  def new
    @corporate = Corporate.new
    #@corporateprofile = Corporateprofile.new

  end

  def create
    @corporate = Corporate.new(corporate_params)
    #@corporateprofile = Corporateprofile.new(corporate_idparams)

    if @corporate.save
      session[:corporate_id] = @corporate.id
      redirect_to @corporate
      #redirect_to corporate_path(current_corporate)
    else
      render :new
    end
  end

private
  def corporate_params
    params.require(:corporate).permit(:firstname, :lastname, :email, :password)
  end

end
```

Corporate Model

```
class Corporate < ActiveRecord::Base

  mount_uploader :corp_image, CorpImageUploader
  mount_uploader :logo, LogoUploader
  has_secure_password

#made by tom to create profile
 after_create :build_profile

 #made by tom to link tables
 has_many :searches, dependent: :destroy
 has_one :corporate_profile,autosave: true, dependent: :destroy



  validates :password, length: { minimum: 8, allow_blank: true }
  validates :firstname, presence: true
  validates :lastname, presence: true
  validates :email, presence: true,
                  format: /\A\S+@\S+\z/,
                  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }



  COMPANY_SIZE = ["1 - 10 Employees", "11 - 50 Employees", "51 - 100 Employees", "101 - 200 Employees", "201 - 500 Employees", "501 - 1000 Employees", "1001 - 5000 Employees", "5001 - 10000 Employees", "10001 - 20000 Employees", "20001 - 50000 Employees", "50001 - 100000 Employees", "100001 - 200000 Employees", "200000+ Employees"]
  INDUSTRY = ['Accounting', 'Airlines/Aviation', "Alternative Disputs Resolution", "Alternative Medicine", "Animation", "Apparel & Fashion", 
    "Architecture & Planning", "Arts & Crafts", "Automotive", "Banking", "Biotechnology", "Broadcast Media", "Building Materials", "Capital Markets", "Commercial Real Estate",
   "Computer Software", "Computer hardware & Network Security", "Construction", 'Consumer Electronics', 'Consumer Services', "Dairy", "Education Management", "E-Learning", "Entertainment", "Information Technology and Services",
   "Hospital & Health Care", "Import and Export", "Internet", "Government", "Legal", "Management Consulting", "Marketing and Advertising", "Military", "Nonprofit Organization Management",
   "Oil & Energy","Professional Training & Coaching", "Restaurants", "Research", "Security and Investigations", "Sports", "Staffing and Recruiting", "Transportation", "Venture Capital & Private Equity", "Other"]
  #validates :sex, inclusion: { in: SEX }

  before_create {generate_token(:auth_token)}

  def send_password_reset
    generate_token(:password_reset_token)
    self.password_reset_sent_at = Time.zone.now
    save!
    CorporateMailer.password_reset(self).deliver
  end

  def generate_token(column)
    begin
      self[column] = SecureRandom.urlsafe_base64
    end while Corporate.exists?(column => self[column])
  end

  def gravatar_id
    Digest::MD5::hexdigest(email.downcase)
  end

  def self.authenticate(email_or_username, password)
    corporate = Corporate.find_by(email: email_or_username)
    corporate && corporate.authenticate(password)
  end

  def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
      new_record?
  end

  #made by tom to build profile
  def build_profile
    CorporateProfile.create(corporate: self) # Associations must be defined correctly for this syntax, avoids using ID's directly.
  end

end
```

Application Controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :expire_hsts
  #helper_method :current_user


private

  def require_signin_corporate
    unless current_corporate
      session[:intended_url] = request.url
      redirect_to new_session_url, alert: "You need to login or register as corporate to post job"
    end
  end
  helper_method :require_signin_corporate

  def require_signin
    unless (current_student || current_corporate)
      session[:intended_url] = request.url
      redirect_to new_session_url, alert: "You need to sign in to have access"
    end
  end

  def require_signin_student
    unless current_student
      session[:intended_url] = request.url
      redirect_to new_session_url, alert: "You need to sign in to have access"
    end
  end
  helper_method :require_signin_student

  def current_corporate
    #@current_corporate ||= Corporate.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
    @current_corporate ||= Corporate.find(session[:corporate_id]) if session[:corporate_id]
  end
  helper_method :current_corporate

  def current_student
    @current_student ||= Student.find_by_auth_token!(cookies[:auth_token]) if cookies[:auth_token]
    #@current_student ||= Student.find(session[:student_id]) if session[:student_id]
  end

  helper_method :current_student


  def current_student?(student)
    current_student == student
  end
  helper_method :current_corporate?

  def current_corporate?(corporate)
    current_corporate == corporate
  end

  helper_method :current_student?

  def correct_student
    @student = Student.friendly.find(params[:id])
    unless current_student?(@student)
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def correct_student?
     #current_student == correct_student
     @correct_student == @student
  end
  helper_method :correct_student?

  def correct_corporate
    @corporate = Corporate.friendly.find(params[:id])
    unless current_corporate?(@corporate)
      redirect_to root_url
    end
  end

  def correct_corporate?
     #current_corporate == correct_corporate
     @correct_corporate == @corporate
  end
  helper_method :correct_corporate?

  def require_admin
    unless current_student_admin? || current_corporate_admin?
      redirect_to root_url, alert: "Unauthorized access!"
    end
  end

  def current_corporate_admin?
    current_corporate && current_corporate.admin?
  end

  def current_student_admin?
    current_student && current_student.admin?
  end

  helper_method :current_corporate_admin?, :current_student_admin?

  def require_author
    unless current_corporate_author?
      redirect_to root_url, alert: "Unauthorized access!"
    end
  end

  def current_corporate_author?
    current_corporate && current_corporate.author?
  end

  helper_method :current_corporate_author?

  def require_pro
    unless current_corporate_pro?
      redirect_to root_url, alert: "Unauthorized access!"
    end
  end

  def current_corporate_pro?
    current_corporate && current_corporate.pro?
  end

  helper_method :current_corporate_pro?


  def expire_hsts
    response.headers["Strict-Transport-Security"] = 'max-age=0'
  end


end
```

Login Form (sessions form)

```
 <%= bootstrap_form_for(:session, url: session_path) do |f| %> 

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.email_field :email, :placeholder => "Email" %> 
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <%= f.password_field :password, :placeholder => "Password" %>
      <%= f.submit "Log in", class: "btn btn-primary block full-width m-b" %> 

    </div>


    <a href="#">
        <small>Forgot password?</small>
    </a>

    <p class="text-muted text-center">
        <small>Do not have an account?</small>
    </p>
    <a class="btn btn-sm btn-white btn-block" href="/signup">Create an account</a>

    <% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using two different classes for authentication makes things more complicated by an order of magnitude - and doing authorization right is hard enough anyways.

Your also right that using a role based system is generally preferable. It helps keeps authorization and authentication separate and will greatly simplify the logic of dealing with users and cut the amount of duplication drastically.

### Refactoring

But lets look at how you can start fixing your current setup.

The first thing you might want to do is stream-line it so that your app uses the same logic for both classes. And ensure that you only have the logic for how the user is serialized / purged from the session in one place in your application.

```
# app/helpers/sessions_helper.rb
module SessionsHelper
  def current_user
    if session[:corporate_id]
      resource_class = Corporate
      id = session[:corporate_id]
    elsif session[:student_id]
      resource_class = Student
      id = session[:student_id]
    end
    @current_user ||= resource_class.find(id)
  end

  def signed_in?
    current_user.present?
  end

  def sign_in!(resource)
    reset_session # this helps combat session fixation attacks
    session[@resource.model_name.i18n_key] = resource.id
    @current_user = resource
  end

  def sign_out!
    reset_session
  end
end
```

One key point is that we use `reset_session` both when signing in and out the user. It invalidates the current session identifier and generates a new session identifier and is an important defence against [session fixation/hijacking attacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#session-hijacking).

We also setup a `current_user` which does not really care if its a `Corporate` or `Student`. To check you can simply do:

```
current_user.is_a?(Corporate)
```

Lets include this helper in our controllers:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  include SessionsHelper
  # ...
end
```

Lets refactor the SessionsController in the same vein:

```
class SessionsController

  # ...
  def create
    @resource = Corporate.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])
    @resource ||= Student.authenticate(params[:email], params[:password])

    if @resource 
       # we need to store this since we are resetting the session.
      intended_url = session[:intended_url]
      sign_in!(@resource)
      flash[:success] = "Welcome back, #{ @resource.firstname }!"
      redirect_to(intended_url || root_path)
    else
      # don't use flash.now when redirecting!
      flash[:warning] = "Kindly login with your email and password!"
      redirect_to '/login'
    end
  end 

  def destroy
    if signed_in?
      sign_out!
      redirect_to root_path, notice: 'You have been signed out!'
    else
      redirect_to root_path, error: "You are not signed in!"
    end
  end
end
```

You also want to change your Corporates / StudentsController create method so that it uses
the same login logic:

```
class CorporatesController

  #...

  def create
    @corporate = Corporate.new(corporate_params)
    #@corporateprofile = Corporateprofile.new(corporate_idparams)

    if @corporate.save
      sign_in! @corporate
      redirect_to @corporate
    else
      render :new
    end
  end
end
```